# Issue adding Word2Vec to Spark pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline

I'm still getting used to Spark but I am having an issue figuring out how to build a pipeline. I have a spark dataframe below and my end goal is to classify each movie by reviewing their plot and classifying them.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCy1z.png)

I am trying to create a pipeline using a stringIndexer, tokenizer, stopwordsremover and word2vec but I am getting the below error. I'm not sure how to resolve it after looking at some similar topics.

```
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="word", outputCol="label")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol = "plot_synopsis", outputCol = "tokenized_terms")
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="tokenized_terms", outputCol="filtered")
word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=5, minCount=0, inputCol="filtered", outputCol="wordVectors")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer, remover, word2Vec, indexer])

encodedData = pipeline.fit(df_expand).transform(df_expand)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-7d237f91c3cf> in <module>
----> 1 encodedData = pipeline.fit(df_expand).transform(df_expand)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    159                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160             else:
--> 161                 return self._fit(dataset)
    162         else:
    163             raise TypeError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    112                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    113                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 114                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    115                     transformers.append(model)
    116                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    159                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    160             else:
--> 161                 return self._fit(dataset)
    162         else:
    163             raise TypeError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 335         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    336         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    337         return self._copyValues(model)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    330         """
    331         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 332         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    333 
    334     def _fit(self, dataset):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o147.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 14) (host.docker.internal executor driver): TaskResultLost (result lost from block manager)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.learnVocab(Word2Vec.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:312)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check once and make sure you are passing Datafrmae to fit() method.
Related issue:
[PySpark :: FP-growth algorithm ( raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325092/pyspark-fp-growth-algorithm-raise-valueerrorparams-must-be-either-a-param)